# How to work inno:zoom Meteor js

Tags: javascript, android, meteor

How does this package work on mobile? 
I have added the package with Meteor add "inno-zoom"

and my HTML is as follows:-

```
{{#HammerTouchArea gestureMap=templateGestures}}
<img class="blue" src="{{img}}" data-action="zoom"/>
    {{/HammerTouchArea}}
```

Does anyone know why this works in the browser but not on android testing device?